# RTTI or a virtual function identifier?

Tags: c++, rtti

What is better solution?
RTTI, or a virtual function which returns an enum value about what class is this?

The problem is this:

I have a base `class GeometryPlace` with derived classes:

- Point
- CircleArc
- LineSegment
- Sphere
- Cone
- Union (of GeometryPlaces)
- Section (of GeometryPlaces)
- Plane
- HalfPlane
- HalfVolume
- etc.....

Then, I have a `std::vector<GeometryPlace*>` and I want to intersect all of these GeometryPlaces.
So, `class GeometryPlace` has these pure virtual functions:

```
GeometryPlace *intersect(GeometryPlace *gp) = 0;
GeometryPlace *intersect(CircleArc *gp) = 0;
/// ... and so on
```

And I use dispatch like this:

```
GeometryPlace *CircleArc::intersect(GeometryPlace *gp) { gp->intersect(static_cast<CircleArc*>(this)); }
```

But in the end of all these, the need is to know, if final GeometryPlace is a `Point` and what is the x,y,z of it, or if it is something else.

And in that problem, I want to use the following code (instead of RTTI):

```
struct GeometryPlace
{
   enum class Type : char { CIRCLEARC, LINESEGMENT, SPHERE, etc.... };
   virtual Type getType() = 0;
}
```

So, what is better? RTTI or this approach?

Comment: Sounds like what you actually need is an any type.  http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/develop/doc/html/any.html  Remember, just because you *can* solve something with inheritance doesn't mean you should.

Comment: For this specific problem (if I understand it correctly) I don't think either will be very helpful. I would consider writing your intersection algorithms as free functions taking two strongly typed parameters.

Comment: Shouldn't `gp->intersect(static_cast<CircleArc*>(gp))` be `gp->intersect(this)` instead?  You are assuming the input `GeometryPlace` is a `CircleArc` and passing it to itself.

Comment: You should expose the information needed by `intersect()` in `GeometryPlace`'s interface. If you don't want to do that for whatever reason, you could use the visitor pattern to avoid RTTI and enums as you propose, but IMO visitor, RTTI, and enums are all unacceptable because they would require up to N^2 implementations of the intersect function, where N is the number of types in the hierarchy.

Comment: You have a double dispatch problem. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_dispatch

Comment: Just in case you've missed it: [GEOS](http://trac.osgeo.org/geos/) I know, this is not an answer to _your_ question but it might save you from re-inventing the wheel :)